# NestJs: How can I inject a Provider that has a constructor with a Mongoose Model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

Hi I have the following code in NestJS.I am using moduleRef and have declared a custom provider named 'blogService'.However I am getting an error that says:

> 'Nest can't resolve dependencies of the blogService (?). Please make
> sure that the argument BlogModel at index [0] is available in the
> AppModule context.'

.What exactly am I doing wrong while declaring the custom provider which is leading to this error as it seems that I am injecting the Mongoose Model as well?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BlogService } from './blog/service/blog.service';
import { Blog } from './blog/schema/blog.schema';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule, getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

        @Module({
          imports: [
            ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, load: [configuration], }),
            MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
          ],
          controllers: [AppController],
          providers: [AppService, {
            provide: 'blogService',
            useFactory: () => BlogService,
            inject: [getModelToken(Blog.name)]
          }],
        
        })
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core';
import { BlogService } from './blog/service/blog.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly modelRef: ModuleRef) { }

  @Get('blogs')
  async getAllBlogs(): Promise<any> {
    const response = await this.modelRef.get('blogService', { strict: false }).getAllBlogs();
    return response;
  }
}
```

**blog.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Blog } from '../schema/blog.schema';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model, Types } from 'mongoose';


@Injectable()
export class BlogService {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(BlogService.name);

    constructor(@InjectModel(Blog.name) private blogModel: Model<Blog>) { }


    async getAllBlogs() {
        try {
            const blogs = await this.blogModel.find().exec();
            return blogs;
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(error.message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure why you're making a custom provider for this, other than possibly academic purposes. Either way, for anything you want to `@InjectModel()` or use `getModelToken()` for, you needx to have a `MongooseModule.forFeature()` call to register the custom provider the `@nestjs/mongoose` package will create for you. Once you have this you can use `@InjectModel()` or a custom provider like

```js
{
  provide: 'blogService',
  inject: [getModelToken(Blog.name)],
  useFactory: (model: Model<Blog>) => new BlogService(model)
}
```

Comment: The reason I created a custom provider for this was that I have the app.controller.ts in which there will be many functions like getAllBlogs,getAllProducts each coming from their respective service i.e  BlogService,ProductService etc so since there would be so many services in app controller I decided to use  custom providers and modelRef.Is there any better way you would suggest?

Comment: I mean, you can do `this.moduleRef.get(BlogService)` as a class instead of a string token. And then you could have a switch based on some incoming parameter and change to the correct class. As you really don't have any custom logic here for the injection I don't see the need for a custom provider. However, why is you `AppController` managing all of this instead of dedicated controllers per feature?

Comment: The app.controller will only handle routes like /blogs , /products etc which are the main GET routes.The respective Blog,Products (Plural)etc controllers will handle routes like /blog(Singular)/id or /product(Singular)/id etc

Comment: But why? Why not let the feature controllers _also_ have a `GET` route for `/` with the controller as `@Controller('/feature')`?

Comment: Yes I was needlessly making it complicated

Comment: Any advise you could give me on the following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118993/nestjs-is-it-possible-to-call-a-third-party-api-inside-a-guard-in-nestjs