# NestJS: Is it possible to call a third party API inside a guard?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, nestjs, okta

I have create a guard to verify Okta tokens in my guard.However to verify there is another external api that needs to be called.Is it possible and advisable to call that api in the below guard? If yes,how can I go about implementing that?

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as OktaJwtVerifier from '@okta/jwt-verifier';

@Injectable()
export class OktaGuard implements CanActivate, OnModuleInit {

  oktaJwtVerifier: any;

  onModuleInit() {
    this.oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
      issuer: 'https://{{host}}.okta.com/oauth2/default',
      clientId: 'your_client_id'
  }
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const token = context.getArgs()[0].headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    return this.oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(token, 'your_audience')
      .then(() => {
        return true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
      });
  }
}
```